# Error message when importing custom HTML to Blogger/Blogspot

Tags: html, css, adobe, blogger, muse

I created a simple website in Adobe Muse that I'd like to use with my Blogger/Blogspot account. Every time I try importing the HTML, I get this error:

```
"Error parsing XML, line 1, column 1: Content is not allowed in prolog".
```

Comment: Can you show the html?

Comment: this generally means that there might be another character befire the start of your <doctype> tag

Comment: Hi, for some reason I'm unable to add the HTML to this post. Can I send it to you?

Comment: The code is on Pastebin http://pastebin.com/8pW0UnHR

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, Blogger template failed to undertand javascript code. So, we have to use html parcel to convert <><><> to `&lt;&gt;`.

Many bloggers have found out a way to solve this error. When, you embed adsense code to blogger template, then you again get error.

So, you can use this website to parse your blogger html code:

http://www.hugestreet.info/2014/09/adsense-ads-converter-tool.html